# Enum.ToString() deprecated?

Tags: c#, enums, resharper, deprecated

When I type `.ToString()` on an `Enum` type in Visual Studio, the Intellisense shows a "strike-through" line through `ToString()` (although it builds and works fine). It seems to indicate that `Enum.ToString()` is deprecated in some way.  Is this true?  If so, why?

[image]

Comment: It's because ToString() is not needed, as that's whats going to be called anyway

Comment: Are you using any extensions for VS that add coloring (such as the strike out)?

Comment: @Reed, I am using ReSharper... don't know if that is doing it

Comment: It's ReSharper. Congratulations-- you've found a bug/feature.

Comment: @dtb: Want to add that to your answer, for future reference?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The Enum.ToString overloads that take an IFormatProvider, [ToString(IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bkcbx85.aspx) and [ToString(String, IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxa5zb70.aspx), are both obsolete, because the IFormatProvider isn't used anyway.

The other overloads, [ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z.aspx) and [ToString(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0h36syw.aspx), are not obsolete.

It's a feature of ReSharper to strike out obsolete class members. It's apparently not very good at it.

Comment: Specifically, the no-arg overload (`ToString()`) that the OP is using is **not** deprecated.

Comment: Well, Intellisense strikes out "ToString" even before I expand the overloads

Comment: @Joel: what do you mean by "strikes out"? Do you get a compiler error or warning? What do you see when you mouse over that code?

Comment: These guys have a similar experience: http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/Coffeehouse/250182-deprecated-string-EnumToStringIFormatProvider-provider/

Comment: @Michael: I think the IntelliSense list shows the method name with a strikethrough font style. That's what I often see it do for deprecated methods.

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't strike through anything by default. I remember Resharper doing such things though.

Comment: @Bolt: but no mouseover text, errors, warnings at all? Hmm. The thread Richard links to, if accurate, seems to indicate that the warning for `ToString(IFormatProvider)` is being shown in error. Joel, what third-party plugins (resharper, etc, as dtb mentions) are you using? I can't reproduce that at home with 08 or 10, but I don't have any plugins here.

Comment: @Michael... I added a screen shot